# How to use Gitlab on mac & local server

Tags: git, macos, ssh, gitlab

I use a Macbook, and I want to push my code on Gitlab to a local server (e.g. 192.168.0.1).

I installed SSH and added the key in Gitlab.

But when I clone the project with `git clone git@slam-System-Senscape:lwc/lsd_shave.git`, I get an error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname slam-system-senscape: nodename nor servname provided, or not known fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Comment: can you ping slam-system-seascape?

Comment: Did you put `slam-system-senscape` in `/etc/hosts`, or have it advertise its hostname via bonjour or something?

Comment: @gregory       ping slam-system-senscape
ping: cannot resolve slam-system-senscape: Unknown host

Comment: @DanLowe I dont know how to do it in mac

Comment: Using `/etc/hosts` is simple, just edit the file and put the entry in there. You will probably need to use sudo, as you can't edit the file as an unprivileged user. The file format is very straightforward: `ip-address hostname`